# Why do I keep getting a run error when using my macro?

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I have a macro that I used on another project and trying to use it on this one.

Currently I have two excel sheets (Excel sheet A and Excel sheet B) and have a macro that is supposed to take a certain range on a certain tab from Excel sheet A and then copy it on a certain tab in Excel sheet B.

The macro is running fine up until a certain point towards the pasting part into Excel sheet B.

The problem is right after ThisWorkbook.Activate:

"Sheets("GTA800-1 Engine Hours").Select"

The full code is listed below:

```
' open the source workbook and select the source sheet
Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:My Documents\Fleet Data (Hrs, Aircraft flying, etc.)\updated_monthly_engine_hrs_97_03.xls"
Sheets("PW150").Select

' copy the source range
Sheets("PW150").Range("B2:G13").Select
Selection.Copy

' select current workbook and paste the values 
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets("GTA800-1 Engine Hours").Select
Sheets("GTA800-1 Engine Hours").Range("B2:G13").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=False

' close the source workbook
Windows("updated_monthly_engine_hrs_97_03.xls").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: are you sure the sheet is named *exactly* as you have it (no leading or trailing spaces, etc"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what the issue was here. I just created a new tab in the worksheet and named it abc just to test it out and then the macro worked just fine. Although the naming was correct on the previous tab above ???

That previous tab was linked to access but I DID delete the link that's the only thing that I can think of that caused the error. Anyone want to follow up on this and confirm ? Otherwise this is my answer on how to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to know the actual error message, but there's no need for all that selecting anyway:

```
With Workbooks.Open(Filename:="D:My Documents\Fleet Data (Hrs, Aircraft flying, etc.)\updated_monthly_engine_hrs_97_03.xls")
    .Sheets("PW150").Range("B2:G13").Copy

    ' select current workbook and paste the values
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GTA800-1 Engine Hours").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, _
                                Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    .Close
End With
```

Comment: Even with that code I'm getting the same error "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range". It's highlighting the code in yellow that you just provided.

Comment: Then the sheet name is not present in the workbook containing the code. Either the name is wrong, or you're looking at the wrong workbook.

Comment: The sheet is present and the name is correct that's what the confusion is. I've triple checked this I've even directly copied the sheet name into the code. GTA800-1 Engine Hours

Comment: Workbook A is declared with the reference and it physically opens up. ThisWoorkbook.Sheets("GTA800-1 Engine Hours") ...................... is a direct reference to the workbook that should have the copied range from Workbook1 being selected. Or am I not understanding that right ?

Comment: Is the code in a module in the same workbook as the "GTA800-1 Engine Hours" worksheet? If it is, the sheet name can't be right. If it isn't, that's the problem with the code.

Comment: Yes code is in the workbook B. When I click the button (which has the macro assigned to it) it then opens workbook A. and then it stops when it gets to that same point gives the error and highlights it in yellow. So everything's working and I guess I'm still not seeing the problem.

Comment: The sheet name cannot be correct then. Can you put the file somewhere (OneDrive / Dropbox etc) - you can remove any data - just for review?

Comment: I could email it. I've made a copy file and deleted just about everything for security purposes.

Comment: Wow - I don't know anyone with no online storage! :) I've temporarily put an email address in my profile.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick possibility. Spaces in tab names often cause problems. Try changing it to an underscore to see if it works properly (both the name and the code clearly).

Comment: I had thought about trying that and hadn't until just now and once more it gets stuck on that line of code. Would the extensions matter at all ? One's a regular old 97-03 workbook and ones a macro embedded one ? Just trying to think of anything at this point.